# Python Luigi: how to create an external dependency/Target?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline, luigi

In Luigi, how can I check if an external resource (in my example an elasticsearch index but it could be anything) exists and if it is not, to create it? My problem is that tasks always have to generate an output file or otherwise they will be considered completed and will not run.

This here https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/595 seems like a hack and I have no run()-method in my class anyway (it is implemented by the parent class CopyToIndex):

```
class UpdateIndex(CopyToIndex):
    source: str = Parameter(default='')

    iteration = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return FilterDataset(self.source)

    def docs(self):
        file_path: str = os.path.join('tmp', '{0}_filtered_output.ldj'.format(self.source))
        file_contents = open(file_path, 'r').read()
        return [json.loads(str(item)) for item in file_contents.strip().split('\n')]

    # properties of parent class CopyToIndex:
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 9200
    index = 'example'
    doc_type = '_doc'
    purge_existing_index = True
    marker_index_hist_size = 1
    mapping = {
        'properties': {
            'name': {'type': 'keyword'},
            'name_suggest': {
                'type': 'completion',
            }
        }
    }
    settings = {
        'number_of_shards': 1,
        'number_of_replicas': 0
    }
```